# What happens to mysql transaction after exceeded wait timeout?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions

I'm new to MySQL database and got some issue with table lock/deadlock. We are running a system with a heavy transactions run everyday and sometime deadlock happened. I would like to know what happened to the transactions if they exceeded wait timeout. Are they canceled (roll-back) ? Do we need to manually run the transaction again or did application auto retry the transaction after deadlock is resolved?
I'm using MySQL 5.7 with Innodb engine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it dosen't matter what db you are using ,if you are using a transaction it will only be committed on success ie if u look closely there is a commit transaction command at the end of try which u write **, unless that line is invoked No changes to the DB will be made** hence you can be assured that it will be roll backed at the situation of timeout error

Comment: yes..i know about that. But the real issue here is related to table lock/deadlock and the transactions were run by user in our system..

Comment: in the case of dead lock  it will wait until time out  after that the transaction will not occur although you can use no lock with it if its a reader functionality